# SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): The operation is insecure

Tags: three.js, filemaker

I'm using 'FileMaker Pro' to show 'three.js' drawing with texture. All is fine inside FMP client, but as soon as I open it in WebDirect, I'm getting this error:

SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): The operation is insecure.

I load 'THREE.JS' from http like this (<> are removed):
script type='text/javascript' src='http://remote.plancher2000.com/three.js-master/build/three.js'/script

I load textures from JavaScript like this:
var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: 'http://remote.plancher2000.com/Escaliers%203D/1-3-2-5-Plancher.jpg' } );

They are both from the same server AND port.
Any clue?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I am hitting the same problem and it looks to me that Safari just does not support this. This is related to CORS support.
Here is a long thread about this issue: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8110

Comment: In Safari, I found out that you can disable this restriction. In the Development menu (you may need to activate it), look for 'Disable local file restrictions'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Safari, I found out that you can disable this restriction. In the Development menu (you may need to activate it), look for 'Disable local file restrictions'.

Some similar setting may exist for other browsers.